# How long does it take for a capacitor to be fully charged if voltage is decreased?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image]

Above is the picture of the circuit pertaining to this question. The question asked for the time it will take for the capacitor to get fully charged when the switch is in position B? So i guess the real question is does it take the same amount of time to charge a capacitor as it does to discharge to get to the stable state? I said the capacitor should be fully charged at t=0 since prior to being in position b the switch is in position a for a long time meaning the capacitor should be fully charged at this point so when the switch moves to position b it would be at its greatest charge since q=CV. The word fully charged used in the question I believe is meant to be at the stable state not max charge. So will it take 5Tau to discharge a charged capacitor to its stable state like it would to charge a capacitor when the capacitor is completely uncharged?

Comment: Hi David and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: This was a test question and it answer was supposed to 5Tau but the wording doesn't really make sense since it says when its fully charged even though its discharging and not charging.

Comment: @DavidCarek, maybe if you show us the rest of your work on this question, we can tell you where you went wrong.  That should satisfy the "What have you tried" requirement.

Comment: It is not clear to me where $5\tau$ comes from. You _never_ reach a steady state - just get "infinitesimally close" with time. If "within 0.67% of the steady state value" is considered is "fully charged" the answer might be correct (assuming you compute $\tau$ correctly) but this is an ill-posed question. And it is very "homework"-ey. As you observe - it was more "fully charged" at the moment the switch was closed than $5\tau$ later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it take the same amount of time to charge a capacitor as it does to discharge to get to the stable state?

Yes, in an RC circuit both of these are $\infty$.

> will it take 5Tau to discharge a charged capacitor to its stable state like it would to charge a capacitor when the capacitor is completely uncharged?

Well, that's not "completely charged" and therefore there is some tolerance $\epsilon$ which you are allowing for, i.e. you want $V = V_{\text{fully-charged}} \pm \epsilon$. If $\epsilon$ is a *fixed voltage* for both circumstances then **no**, it will not take the same time $k ~\tau$ but rather $k$ will be different.

However, if $\epsilon$ is a *fixed percentage* of $V_{\text{fully-charged}} - V_{\text{start}}$ then in general yes, you should see that the $k$ is the same.

So the expression is, if you start at $V_0$ and you're charging to $V_1$, **regardless of which one is higher than the other one** (whether you're charging or discharging), the voltage across the capacitor is $$V(t) = V_1 - (V_1 - V_0) \exp\left(\frac {-t}{RC} \right).$$You can see that for $t = 0$ this is just $V_1 - (V_1 - V_0) = V_0,$ and for $t \to \infty$ we see $V_1 - 0 = V_1$. So this works whatever sign the difference is.

But that sign is useful: let $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = x/|x|$ be the "sign function" that is $1$ if $x > 0$, or $0$ if $x = 0$, or $-1$ if $x < 0.$

For the time $t = k ~R~C$ where $V = V_1 - \operatorname{sgn}(V_1 - V_0)~\epsilon$ (chosen so $\epsilon$ is always positive) you can then work out that $$\frac{V_1 - V_0}{|V_1 - V_0|} ~ \epsilon = (V_1 - V_0) ~ e^{-k},$$ so that $$k = -\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon}{|V_1 - V_0|}\right)$$and so if you're always judging that "close enough" error-tolerance voltage as a percentage of $V_1 - V_0$, you will always have the same $k$, but anything else will change it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it will never get fully (dis)charged, i.e., its voltage drop will never match the supply.

The time constant is always the same, because it does not depend on the boundary conditions of your equations. To answer your question, all time scales remain the same. That means if you define the system to be stable after $5\tau$ (which is reasonable), then it will be so.

Comment: I understand that it will never fully discharge but the time it takes to discharge until it is in its stable state meaning I=0, is that about equal to the time it takes for the capacitor to charge to that stable state if the capacitor is completely uncharged?

Comment: $I$ will never be 0; and yes, that's what I mean by "all time scales are the same".